# Java program won't compile

Tags: java

I'm making this program under jgrasp and I'm getting an error. I have checked the spelling and the grammar of my program and it seems to be correct. Please help me -- is there something I'm missing that's causing all my errors?

```
import javax.swing.*;


public class Testscore
{
   public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
       int numberofTests = 0;

       double grade = new double[numberofTests];

       double startgrade = 0;

        int x = 1 ;

       String strInput;

    // Get how many tests are used

       strInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How many tests do you have? ");
       numberofTests = Integer.parseInt(strInput);

       grade = new double[(int) numberofTests];
         do

         {

       for (int index = 0; index < grade.length; index++)
       {
           strInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Test Score." + (index + 1));
           grade = Double.parseDouble(strInput);

           if (grade[index] < 0 || grade[index] > 100 )
           {   
               try 
                {
                   throw new InvalidTestScore();
                    x=2;
                }

               catch (InvalidTestScore e)
               {
                   e.printlnStackTrace();
                    system.out.println ("Choose a test score between 0 and 100");
               }
           }   
       }
       }
         while (x==1);

       for (int index = 0; index < grade.length; index++ )

            {
                startgrade += grade[index];
            }

            average = startgrade/grade.length;

            System.out.print("The average is: " + average);

    }
}
```

Here are the errors I am getting.

```
Testscore.java:12: incompatible types

found   : double[]

required: double

       double grade = new double[numberofTests];

                      ^
Testscore.java:25: incompatible types

found   : double[]

required: double

       grade = new double[(int) numberofTests];

               ^
Testscore.java:30: double cannot be dereferenced

       for (int index = 0; index < grade.length; index++)
                                        ^
Testscore.java:35: array required, but double found

           if (grade[index] < 0 || grade[index] > 100 )
                    ^
Testscore.java:35: array required, but double found

           if (grade[index] < 0 || grade[index] > 100 )
                                        ^
Testscore.java:39: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class InvalidTestScore
location: class Testscore
                   throw new InvalidTestScore();
                             ^
Testscore.java:43: cannot find symbol

symbol  : class InvalidTestScore

location: class Testscore

               catch (InvalidTestScore e)
                      ^
Testscore.java:46: package system does not exist

                    system.out.println ("Choose a test score between 0 

and 100");
                          ^
Testscore.java:53: double cannot be dereferenced

       for (int index = 0; index < grade.length; index++ )
                                        ^
Testscore.java:56: array required, but double found

                startgrade += grade[index];

     ^
Testscore.java:59: cannot find symbol

symbol  : variable average

location: class Testscore

            average = startgrade/grade.length;
            ^
Testscore.java:59: double cannot be dereferenced

            average = startgrade/grade.length;
                                      ^
Testscore.java:61: cannot find symbol

symbol  : variable average

location: class Testscore

            System.out.print("The average is: " + average);
                                                  ^
13 errors
```

Comment: You're that program but it just won't? This sounds serious... are you sure you didn't forget a "homework" tag from your question?

Comment: You're need to change it to. Otherwise it always won't.

Answer (score 6):

On line 12, try changing

```
double grade = new double[numberofTests];
```

to

```
double[] grade = new double[numberofTests];
```

All of the subsequent errors appear to be consequences of the compiler thinking that `grade` is a `double` instead of an array of them. For example, the mention of "dereferencing" refers to indexing into an array; it's not reasonable to index into a scalar `double`.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is pretty helpful, it tells you what line you have an error on, and what the error is.

The first error is on line 12 and tells you that you've assigned an array reference to something that's not an array, you should change

```
 double grade = new double[numberofTests];
```

to

```
double grade[] = new double[numberofTests];
```

The next one, on line 25 is similar.
The next 3 errors are because of the two previous ones since you declared `grade` as just a double but later on try to use it as an array.

The error on line 39 `Testscore.java:39: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class InvalidTestScore` 
Means that the compiler cannot find your InvalidTestScore class - where is it ? You should compiler that class as well.

The error on line 46 is that `system.out.println` should be `System.out.println` (capital S in System)

The error on line 59 says that there is no variable named `average` You can define it as the result of the expression you have there, so just change `average = startgrade/grade.length;` to `double average = startgrade/grade.length;`